# number of subsets of the positive integers that whose members sum to n

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of subsets of the positive integers that whose members sum to n. Example, subsets of the positive integers that whose members sum to 5. These are the subsets:

{5},{4,1},{3,2},{3,1,1},{2,2,1},{2,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1}

Example: n = 6

{6},{5,1},{4,2},{3,3},{4,1,1},{3,2,1},{2,2,2},{3,1,1,1},{2,2,1,1},{2,1,1,1,1},{1,1,1,1,1,1}

what is the general formula for the number of sets that have all members sum to n?

Comment: I will point out that you are using *multisets*, not sets.  (*repitition is not allowed in ordinary sets, so $\{2,2,1,1\}$ is not technically a set as you wanted it to be*).  The concept you are looking for are what are known as [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).  Read [further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function_formulas) down the page for some formulae.

Comment: OEIS is always good https://oeis.org/A000041

Answer (score 1):

So you're going to find the different ways for partitioning a number. There is a very nice explanation here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 0):

From the positive integers whose sum equals '(n+1)',it means we are looking for the partition of '(n+1)'.
Have, a look at this,if a set contains 'n' elements then the number of partitions of the set is,$P(n+1)= \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{i}P(i)$,where $P(0)=1,P(1)=1$.

For your query, repalce (n+1) by 'n' in the above formula.

General formula for the number of sets that have all members whose sum equals 'n'is $2^{P(n)}-1(empty set)$.

Comment: @bob: approve it,if it is helpful for you.